# Bootstrap active class not working with django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use active class with django, so the user knows what page they are on but It's not working. I tried tried using it like this

```
<div class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
<ul class="pagination">
{% for i in paginator.page_range %}
 <li {% if page_obj.number == i %} class="active" {% endif %}><a href="?tags={{i}}">{{i}}</a><li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but it's not working. What is the proper syntax to make this work?

I have looked at a few posts on here and tried

```
class="{% if page_obj.number == i %} active {% endif %}"
```

but thishasn't worked either
thanks in advance

Comment: First things first: figure out if it's a bootstrap issue or a django issue. Is the "active" class rendering in your HTML? If not, what is? You can always add debug statements such as `{{ page_obj.number }}` and `{{ i }}` in your loop, to see what you're working with.

Comment: Apologies; my answer was mistaken, and I've deleted it. For the record, though, AFAIK stands for "as far as I know." Also, although they may have been correct for this case, w3schools is not the most reliable resource; I (and many others) recommend referring to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) for reference on CSS, HTML, etc.

Comment: @nthall thanks for the response on both counts